# Who or what is this Martian creature?

Tags: character-identification, a-trip-to-mars

Thomas Alva Edison's short silent film *[A Trip to Mars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_yr7TyJXoQ)* (1910) shows what is thought to be the first cinematic Martian. The film, which was most likely inspired by Georges Méliès, depicts a big Martian with great extended ears holding in his palm a scientist who, after mixing two powders, develops an anti-gravity mix and ends himself on Mars. The film also reveals that huge tree beings govern the planet Mars. I wonder whether it has been known for over a century who or what this Martian creature is. Is it a conscious tree? an emperor? a king? a tyrant?

[image: Still image from the short film A Trip to Mars (1910)]

Comment: It looks reasonably similar to the tree people in the prior scene.  I doubt there's enough source material to be dogmatic on anything.  Parsimony would imply one shouldn't invent a second race of giant martians in a 5 minute silent film when one race will do.  Presumably he was a nice martian that sent the guy back to Earth in a nice snowball rather than a hard vacuum trip.